# Using variables, replacing SQL select statements and PHP Prepare statements. Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have some working code that uses a SQL select statement within it. As a static bit of code, it works great, however, I want to be able to use variables in it. So, doing my research, everyone says you should use PHP Prepare statements, to keep things safe and secure. So, my old code looks something like this:

```
    /*** MY OLD WORKING CODE ***/ 
    /*** SQL Query ***/   
    $sql = "SELECT tickets.ref AS `Ticket Number` ......
    .....BLAH................INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
    organizations.name = 'NAMEIWANTTOUSE' ";

    /*** For Each Loop to Build Table ***/
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){ 
     echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<td bgcolor=89FF95 align=center>".$row['Ticket Number']."</td>"; 
       ETC..................
    } 
    $sql->closeCursor();
```

My new code, that Im trying to get working.. seems to be doing nothing. I know Im not too far out with it, but I just cant get to grips with which variable I should be pushing into my FOREACH loop.. or if I have actually got the PHP Prepare statement right at all?

Any suggestions anyone?

```
    /*** MY NEW NOT WORKING CODE ***/ 
    /*** Variables ***/
    $NAME = 'NAMEIWANTTOUSE';
    $DAYS = '30';

    /*** Prepare the SQL Query ***/
    $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT tickets.ref AS `Ticket Number` .......
    ....BLAH................INTERVAL :DAYS DAY) AND
    organizations.name = :NAME ");

    $stmt->bindParam(":DAYS", $DAYS);
    $stmt->bindParam(":NAME", $NAME);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();

    /*** Put each return from SQL into a Variable? ***/
    $MySQLQuery = $stmt->fetchAll();

    /*** For Each Loop to Build Table ***/
    foreach ($dbh->query($MySQLQuery) as $row){ 
     echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<td>".$row['Ticket Number']."</td>"; 
       ETC..................
    } 
    $sql->closeCursor();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly do have it, except that you ought not be calling `query()` in the loop.  The result set has already been fetched into `$MySQLQuery`.  [`fetchAll()` returns a 2D array](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), unlike the old `mysql_query()` which returned a result resource that needed to be looped over with `mysql_fetch_*()`.

```
// Following fetchAll(), $MySQLQuery is a 2D array containing your rowset.
foreach ($MySQLQuery as $row){ 
 echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>".$row['Ticket Number']."</td>"; 
   ETC.........
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for that. Ive tried changing my code and its still not working. The SQL statement is exactly the same bar the :NAME and :DAYS. The actual original staement uses 'NAMEIWANTTUSE' (note the quotes).. so do I have to do something there to make :NAME work? Also, bindparam, I also see you may need to specify a String Value? In short, the new code gives me a blank screen.. the old code, returns the results. Any suggestions on how to debug? Thanks

Comment: The error Im getting seems to be to do with the variable in my SELECT statement PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in E:\test.php on line 15